# cache.region.factory_class not showing up in hibernate configuration recommendations

Tags: hibernate, second-level-cache

I am trying to implement second level cache in hibernate.
In the hibernate.cfg.xml file, I am writing the following line

```
<property name = "cache.region.factory_class"></property>
```

The problem is that my ide is not showing cache.region.factory_class in recommendations. Is this property depracated or am I doing something wrong? My hibernate version is 5.6.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Hibernate.cfg.xml it should be `hibernate.cache.region.factory_class`

So for instance when using a JCache:

```
    <property name="hibernate.cache.region.factory_class">org.hibernate.cache.jcache.JCacheRegionFactory</property>
```